# How to call function in __constructor using laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am fetching menus from database based on user rights and displaying it to my web page but if i access any url whose access i don't have then too it opens that page.
For this i have created and called access_denied function which redirect user's home page.
I have called access_denied function from constructor of AuthController because AuthController gets loaded on each page.

I have used following code

AuthController

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->accessDenied();
}

public function accessDenied() 
    {
        $url_segment1 = Request::segment(1);
        $url_segment2 = Request::segment(2);

        $url_segment = $url_segment1 . '/' . $url_segment2;
        $user_data = Auth::user()->toArray();
        $dadmin = array_keys($user_data['admin']);
        //this is sample of array 
        //    $user_data['admin'] => Array
        //          (
        //           [admin/roles] => 1
        //          )
        if (!in_array($url_segment, $dadmin)) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }    
    }
```

But I am getting following error

```
Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::segment() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
```

If i using incorrect process then please suggest me correct way to redirect unauthorised user on home page.

Comment: use a middleware instead of access denied function

Comment: where use middleware in routing??? @AchrafKhouadja

Comment: excuse me?  i couldnt understand

Comment: i mean how to use middleware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should create a middleware. In a command prompt type:

```
php artisan make:middleware AccessDenyMiddleware
```

Then you go to app/Http/Middleware/AccessDenyMiddleware.php and fill in the handle function {your own code}

```
    $url_segment1 = Request::segment(1);
    $url_segment2 = Request::segment(2);

    $url_segment = $url_segment1 . '/' . $url_segment2;
    $user_data = Auth::user()->toArray();
    $dadmin = array_keys($user_data['admin']);
    //this is sample of array 
    //    $user_data['admin'] => Array
    //          (
    //           [admin/roles] => 1
    //          )
    if (!in_array($url_segment, $dadmin)) {
        return redirect('/home');
    }
```

But add the following line

```
return $next($request); // If passed, proceed with the route
```

Then, in a route, you should type:

```
Route::get('/yoururlhere', ['middleware' => 'AccessDenyMiddleware', function() { /* Put your work here */ } ]);
```

There are much better approaches. Like Authorisation if you are using Laravel 5.2

Or maybe change the default Authenticate middleware if you are using Laravel 5

Answer (score 1):

You can use a middleware for thath https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#introduction.

php artisan make:middleware RoleRouteMiddleware

You should put thath code in the handle method of the middleware "App\Http\Middleware\RoleRouteMiddleware" and use the $request variable instead of the facade Request.

The middleware would filter earch request to your app.

Register a middleware, add it on app/Http/Kernel.php at routeMiddleware array

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ....
    'alias' => App\Http\Middleware\RoleRouteMiddleware::class,
];
```

and then use it on specific routes like this:

```
Route::get('admin/profile', ['middleware' => 'alias', function () {
    //your code here
}]);
```

or in route gruoups:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'alias', function () {
    //your filtered routes
}]);
```